# How to use mount command in fstab file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcsfuse, fstab

After creating `/mnt/bucket` folder which is to be used as a local mounting-point for Google Bucket:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/bucket
sudo chmod 777 /mnt/bucket
```

I can successfully `mount` it to `mybucket` Google Bucket by simply typing `sudo mount` followed by with all its endless arguments in Ubuntu terminal, like so:

```
sudo mount -t gcsfuse -o key_file=/keys/key.json -o rw -o allow_other -o file_mode=777 -o dir_mode=777 mybucket /mnt/bucket
```

Since I am supplying `mount` command with the `-o key_file=path/to/key.json` option the `bucket` that is mounted on `/mnt/bucket` folder can be accessed with the full access permissions (users can read, write, create, delete files and folders stored on Bucket).

But the same command does not run properly if put inside of `/etc/fstab` file which is supposed to be executed at the time the machine boots.
Here is the syntax as it was put inside of `/etc/fstab` file (the same command just no `sudo` and `mount` at the beginning):

```
-t gcsfuse -o key_file=/keys/key.json -o rw -o allow_other -o file_mode=777 -o dir_mode=777 mybucket /mnt/bucket
```

Comment: Please refer to fstab file format, where proper order must be kept. 1st - physical point, 2nd - mount point, 3rd - fs type ... etc

Comment: This is a sysadmin question, not a programming one.  It might be suitable for [unix.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of a line in `/etc/fstab` is:

```
<device> <mount-point> <filesystem-type> <comma-separated-options> <dump=0|1> <fsck=0|1>
```

You need to rearrange the mount command you have. `-t` is the filesystem type. `-o` are the options. `mybucket` is the device. `/mnt/bucket` is the mount point. End result, add this line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
mybucket /mnt/bucket gcsfuse key_file=/keys/key.json,rw,allow_other,file_mode=777,dir_mode=777 0 0
```

Comment: `noauto` flag could be used to avoid a system lock on a boot. If a system doesn't run the commands defined in `/etc/fstab` file it could become irresponsive.